# Подпись документа стилусом на сайте

Tags: javascript, html5, вёрстка, canvas, ecmascript-6

На сайт необходимо добавить несколько блоков "подписи соглашения" для документов с поддержкой стилуса или сенсорного экрана. Подскажите пожалуйста с помощью чего это можно реализовать. Если кто сталкивался с таким же вопросом подскажите, как вы его решили?

Спасибо))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам потребуется **canvas** для рисования. Далее вы можете вытянуть его содержимое в [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Blob) и сохранить на компьютер/выгрузить на сервер...

```
<canvas width="500" height="300"></canvas>
<button>save to png</button>
<script>
    (function() {
        const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
        const button = document.querySelector("button");

        let click = false;
        let xCoord = NaN;
        let yCoord = NaN;

        const  cntx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        cntx.strokeStyle = "red";
        cntx.lineWidth = 10;
        cntx.lineCap = "round";
        cntx.fillStyle = "#fff";
        cntx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        canvas.onmousedown = canvas.ontouchstart  = (e) => {
            click = true;
            xCoord = (e.pageX || parseInt(e.touches[0].pageX)) - canvas.offsetLeft;
            yCoord = (e.pageY || parseInt(e.touches[0].pageY)) - canvas.offsetTop;
        };
        canvas.onmouseup = canvas.ontouchend = () => {
            click = false;
        };
        canvas.click = () => {
            click = false;
        };
        canvas.onmousemove = canvas.ontouchmove = (e) => {
            if (click === true) {
                cntx.beginPath();
                cntx.moveTo(
                    (e.pageX || parseInt(e.touches[0].pageX)) - canvas.offsetLeft,
                    (e.pageY || parseInt(e.touches[0].pageY)) - canvas.offsetTop,
                );
                cntx.lineTo(xCoord, yCoord);
                cntx.stroke();
                cntx.closePath();
                xCoord = (e.pageX || parseInt(e.touches[0].pageX))- canvas.offsetLeft;
                yCoord = (e.pageY || parseInt(e.touches[0].pageY)) - canvas.offsetTop;
            } else {
                return;
            }
        };
        button.onclick = () => {
            const data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 100);
            const link = document.createElement("a");
            link.href = data;
            link.download = "image.png";
            link.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data);
        };
    })();
</script>
```

Конструкция `(e.pageX || parseInt(e.touches[0].pageX))` позволяет поддерживать события сенсорного экрана на равне с движением мыши.

Comment: подскажите, у меня canvas находиться внизу основной страницы, когда начинаю рисовать курсор рисует намного ниже, чем должно быть. Но когда открыла новый документ (только данный код) все работает отлично.

Answer (score 0):

Так же Нашла, на hithab готовое решение написанное с помощью HTML5 canvas, которое предлагает свой вариант подписи. Опробовала на практике, все работает. https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad